# Get the first integer from a txt file using bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, integer, extract

How could I (under ubuntu) get the first integer from a bowl of soup

Comment: is the Hash always after the numbers?

Comment: And does the string always start with the integer you want to save?

Answer (score 2):

Using pure BASH:

```
line='321#somewords-and-numbers32452352'
[[ "$line" =~ ^[^0-9]*([0-9]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
321
```

Or using `sed`:

```
sed 's/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*$/\1/' <<< "$line"
321
```

Comment: I coped your regex and got "s/^ÿ^0-9¦*½(ÿ0-9¦½+½).*$/½1/". WHAT IS IT???

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'abc321#somewords-and-numbers32452352' | grep -oP '^[^0-9]*\K[0-9]+'
```

Output:

```
321
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sed and a string match to return the first number in the string.

`echo $line | sed -e 's/^[^0-9]*\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/'`

The first part of the regular expression `[^0-9]*` is to removing any non-numeric leading characters if they are present.